# Change icons according to visual studio theme changes

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, vsix

I want to change image in custom tool window using wpf,when user changes visual studio theme (dark,light,blue). like visual studio does.

e.g  image1, image2
when "dark" theme select i want to show image1, switch to "light" then image 2 should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is not the right way...wpf is vectoriel, replace your icon with xaml resources (view+canvas, etc) and change only the brushes
check [code sample](http://archx.codeplex.com/) and [icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/)